# What user should apache and PHP be running as? What permissions should /var/www files have?

Tags: linux, security, users, php, apache-httpd

I just spun up an Ubuntu 11.10 box and then ran `apt-get install apache2 php5` to install apache2 and PHP 5 on the box. Now it is functioning as a "web server" and it loads the "It Works!" page. Now I'm trying to tighten up security and I have the following questions about linux web servers:

1. Who should apache be running as?
2. What group(s) should this user be in?
3. What package(s) can make PHP (and Apache?) run as the owner of the files? (like on shared web hosts) Should I use these packages? Are they easy / feasible to maintain on a small system?
4. What should the default permissions be for files and folders being served out to the web with apache running as `www-data`? For apache/php running as the user?

I have done the following things in examination of the default setup:

#### File Structure

When I `cd /` and do a `ls -al` listing of the contents, I see `/var`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 2012-02-04 20:47 var/
```

If I `cd` into `var` and do `ls -al` I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2012-02-04 20:47 www/
```

Finally, inside `/var/www` I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2012-02-04 20:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 2012-02-04 20:47 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  177 2012-02-04 20:47 index.html
```

My key takeaway is that so far all of these files belong to `root:root`, files have permissions of 644, and directories have permissions of 755.

#### Apache's Permissions

If I create a file as root in `/var/www/test.php` with the contents:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('whoami');
```

and load that file into a browser it tells me `www-data`, which is the same as in the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

If I do `ps aux | grep -i apache` I see the following:

```
root      1916  1.2 104664  7488 Ss   20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1920  0.8 105144  5436 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1921  1.0 105144  6312 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1922  0.7 104688  4624 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1923  0.7 104688  4624 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1924  0.7 104688  4624 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1925  0.7 104688  4624 S    20:47 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

So who is apache running as? It looks like perhaps the first process is as `root`, maybe from the `/etc/init.d/apache` script when the system started, and the other ones as `www-data` spawned from the first. Is that correct?

Next, if I type in `groups www-data` then I see `www-data : www-data` - so it looks to only be in the `www-data` group. I'm guessing this is standard practice as well.

#### Shared Hosting and Security

So if I understand things correctly, if apache is running as `www-data` and I want apache to be able to read a directory, the `x` bit needs to be set for the world (other) group (`o+x`), and that also needs to be set on all parent directories all the way  up the chain (`www`, `var`). And if I want apache to be able to read from a file, then the `o+r` bit needs to be set.

Unfortunately I believe this introduces a security hole for multiple applications and/or multiple users on the same linux box: All web files need to be world-readable, and so they are also accessible by other applications and other users on the system. If one application installed on the system had a security vulnerability that allowed raw, unvalidated user input, which was then executed by PHP, a remote attacker could then browse all the other files on the web system which were world readable. Likewise, if the box had multiple users, and a user knew the path of another user's web files, s/he could then read the file contents (and see sensitive things like database connection strings, etc).

I've heard of two packages, `suphp` and `phpsuexec` that deal with allowing users' files to be served out "as them" on a shared system. One of the niceties of this is that it allows web applications (like Wordpress) to create and modify files - very helpful for adding themes, plugins, and upgrading software. Of course it is probably more secure to do these things manually, but can a compromise be made perhaps with one of the packages mentioned above? Or by possibly using `chown` to make the wordpress directory group belong to `www-data` and set the sticky bit on the group (`g+s`)?

I have only used these as the end user of a web hosting company, and so I don't know the ins-and-outs of them, and if they are even reasonable to install on a small system, or if there are some other security measures I should use instead, but I thought I would mention them here as they seem like one possible way to address some of my concerns.

#### Back to the Questions

1. Who should apache be running as?
2. What group(s) should this user be in?
3. What package(s) can make PHP (and Apache?) run as the owner of the files? (like on shared web hosts) Should I use these packages? Are they easy / feasible to maintain on a small system?
4. What should the default permissions be for files and folders being served out to the web with apache running as `www-data`? For apache/php running as the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/339948/user-permissions-for-both-apache-and-local-user/357977

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. not root
2. not root
3. [SuEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html)
4. Depends. 644 for files and 755 for folders are a safeish default.

**Don't change ownership of anything to www-data unless you want php to be able to edit the contents of that file/folder**

Irrespective of anything else you do: folders need read and execute permissions for the user to find files; files need read permissions for the user to read them. If you get any permissions errors when changing things - you've managed to remove these fundamentally required permissions.

If you are not writing any files via your php application, you can leave files owned by you:you. In this circumstance the world permission (xx4/5) is the one which applies.

If you leave the files as owned by you:you with file permissions of 644 (files) what that would mean is that *only* you can edit the website files - www-data is not you - so it cannot edit the files.

If you want to restrict access to apache + you and block out all other access `chown -R you:www-data *`. With file permissions of 640 and folder permissions of 750 you can edit, www-data can read - because then apache reads the group permission (x4/5x).

Restrict to a minimum the paths you allow apache/php to write to - if there's a tmp dir the application needs to write to - allow it to write to *that folder only* - and for any writable locations if at all possible make sure it's *outside* the document root or take steps to ensure this writable path is not web-accessible.

Note that "you" should *not* be root. Allowing direct ssh access as root is an indicator of other security lapses (such as *not* disallowing password login), but that's a whole bunch of questions unto itself.

Answer (score 10):

> So if I understand things correctly, if apache is running as www-data
>   and I want apache to be able to read a directory, the x bit needs to
>   be set for the world (other) group (o+x), and that also needs to be
>   set on all parent directories all the way up the chain (www, var). And
>   if I want apache to be able to read from a file, then the o+r bit
>   needs to be set.

This is not true, you don't have to set `rwx` for 'other'. You should change the owner and/or group of the particular folder/file you are trying to protect. E.g.:

```
chown -R cwd:www-data /var/www/cwd.com
chmod 750 /var/www/cwd.com
```

Now only members of the group `www-data` can read `/var/www/cwd.com`. And only you (cwd) can write to it. If you want to allow your applications (through Apache) to write/modify files in that directory too you chmod it to 770.

I think this covers all your issues, I see no reason to change the user apache is running under.

Comment: Thank you. It's not a bad solution, but if one user knows the path to another user's file, the could write a script that would read the contents of the file, and then load that in the web browser, which would run it as apache - effectively reading the file from the other user's directory. Does that make sense? So even if you set the folder permissions to 750 there is still a potential security vulnerability.

Comment: @cwd did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @cwd This was the exact question that I had. That's why I asked this: http://serverfault.com/questions/807723/www-data-security-issue-across-multiple-sites-in-a-vps/807728#807728